# Can't open csv file with Buffered Reader

Tags: java, android, sql, database, csv

I'm trying to read the csv file which is in my res/raw/friends.csv and import it record by record in my database. However, 3rd line of my function seems to unable to either locate or open the file and exiting with javaNULLPointerException. What should I do?

```
 public void fillBase(SQLiteDatabase db){
        BufferedReader in=null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("raw/friends.csv")); 
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); //end up going here!
        }
        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] parts = line.split(",");
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("Name", parts[0]); 

                // Insert the data into the database
                db.insert(FRIENDS, null, values); // insert your table name
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure your relative path is correct? Why not just use the full path if you're not sure? If it is correct, then it's probably a permission issue on the file you are trying to read.

Comment: @ksealey So how it should look like?

Comment: Start at the root. If you're on windows, right click on the file you want to open, click "properties" and it will show you the absolute location starting from C: or whatever drive it may be

Comment: @ksealey I'm doing it on Mint. Even like this   in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/home/andrey/AndroidStudioProjects/whatever/app/src/main/res/raw/friends.csv"));  it still gives a same exception

Comment: Well then it's probably a permission issue. If you're on linux I would change the user and group to bin `(sudo chown -R bin:bin /home/andrey/AndroidStudioProjects/whatever/app/src/main/res/raw/)` and add reading and writing for everybody `(sudo chmod -R ugo+rw )` to the directory holding the file and any subdirectories

Comment: @ksealey still doesn't work

Comment: I've even tried to move it to home with all permissions and it still doesn't want to get the file. Maybe it's something in the manifest?

Comment: Forget this! You are using paths from your development machine and they naturally doesent exist when the app is deployed on a device (or an emulator)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should have just one big try-catch block and not two; if the first fail the 2nd will always fail with a NullPointerException.

Second, you can't use file names and paths to access resources in an Android app. That only works for desktop Java programs.

Instead you must use getResources().openRawResource()

Here's a working version of your code:

```
 public void fillBase(SQLiteDatabase db){
        try {
        BufferedReader in= new BufferedReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.friends)); 
        String line = null;
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] parts = line.split(",");
                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put("Name", parts[0]); 

                // Insert the data into the database
                db.insert(FRIENDS, null, values); // insert your table name
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: "Cannot resolve method getResources()", and no options offered for importing a class or something

Comment: getResources() is a method from the Activity class (actually its superclass Context). 
You'll need a Context in the code to be able to access the app's files